# Does TableBatchOperation guarantee that all entities will have same Timestamp field value?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm adding multiple entries to Azure CloudTable:

```
TableBatchOperation tableBatchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    tableBatchOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
}
table.ExecuteBatch(tableBatchOperation);
```

Is there any guarantee that all entries inserted / updated in this batch operation will have the same [Timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.timestamp.aspx) property value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: entities inserted in the same batch can have different timestamps.

It depends on the batch size and I guess current load of Table Service. 
I wrote a simple unit test to check that, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/plentysmart/93775424af5bafe7c254) and in one batch of 100 items (every with 30KB string property) I can see few different timestamps(ticks):

```
635516539271235769
635516539271245771
635516539271225762
```

but for smaller batches timestamp is sometimes the same.

Differences are really small (ticks) but for sure I would not depend on timestamp since it's internal Azure Table Service property, and it changes on every update.

I would rather add another property to an entity with a batch timestamp.